# Binary Rejection - Interface Error on Interface.plist - Watch App

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, watchkit, watchapp

Trying to submit using Xcode (6C131e) and we keep getting the following error:

> Interface Error - The '****** WatchKit App.app/Interface.plist' file
>   in watch application '******.app/PlugIns/******WatchKit
>   Extension.appex/****** WatchKit App.app' has the following error: The
>   property '#/root' of type Array did not match one or more of the
>   required schemas. The schema specific errors were: - anyOf #0: - The
>   property '#/root' of type Array did not match the following type:
>   string - anyOf #1: - The property '#/root' of type Array did not match
>   the following type: object Once these issues have been corrected, you
>   can then redeliver the corrected binary.

We are using a page-based navigation structure for our Watch App, with our "Main Entry Point" InterfaceController being connect to subsequent pages using the "next page" segue relationship.

If we look at Interface.plist, under "root" there is in fact an Array (not string or "object") with an entry for each of the view controllers that we've linked to Main. However, as this plist is Xcode generated, it seems that this is expected behavior (unless our storyboard is configured incorrectly).

Anybody else encountered this or have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: We're also getting a similar error, but ours is saying a "field of type String did not match the following type: number". This Interface.plist is generated by Xcode though

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit WatchKit apps at the moment. Please wait for an official Apple announcement.